# Passing Parameters into "java -jar ords.war"

Tags: java, bash, oracle-ords

I'm an Oracle DBA and we script a lot of our work using Bash. We use APEX and ORDS at my place of work and I run "java -jar ords.war" uninstall/install etc quite frequently and have to do it by hand. I just want to script this and automatically supply the parameters through the bash script.

If I run the command manually, then when I'm prompted, I have to enter the relevant parameters: host name, port, sid, sys password and apps password.

So, how do I provide these parameters using a bash script? I've Googled a fair bit and tried putting the parameters in quotes or using an external file but I get no joy. Any thoughts?

EDIT for Tripleee:

If this post is a duplicate of another then any chance you could point me in the right direction as I cannot find it.

EDIT for REW:

We setup clone of Oracle EBS databases quite frequently. Everything is scripted other than the reconfiguration of ORDS. We do this on multiple instances so our scripts work out what the SID, port, server name etc is and then supplies them to various programs such as ADADMIN etc. All I'm trying to do is run "java -jar ords.war uninstall". When that's is run manually you have to supply the program with 5 parameters from the command line (server name, port, SID, sys password and apps password). I just want to automate the supplying of those parameters but each time I get the "WARNING: Console is unavailable and required for Advanced installation" error message and it all stops.

Comment: See if this helps http://osr507doc.xinuos.com/en/OSUserG/_Passing_to_shell_script.html

Comment: This article talks about passing parameters into a shell script. WHat I need to know is how to call a java program, specifically one that is "java -jar ords.war" because if  I use this:"java -jar ords.war << EOF param1, param2, param3 ... EOF I get a "WARNING: Console is unavailable and required for Advanced installation" and the process just stops.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setup the configuration directory via scripts, then just use the 'configdir' command to point configure the ords.war to point to it:

```
java -jar ords.war configdir </path/to/config>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e56293/about-REST-configuration-files.htm#AELIG7202

Comment: See the original post as the text is too long for this box.